# properties of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following matrix 
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}-A& -B^T\\ -B &0\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A>0$ and $B$ is a matrix such that the diagonal entries of $B$ are all zero and the rest of the entries are either zero or $1$, and $(I-B) \mathbf{1}=0$ and $\mathbf{1}^T(I-B)=0$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones).
Do the eigenvalues of $C$ have special properties?

Comment: Is anything else known about $A$?

Comment: Are you sure about $B\mathbf 1=0$? If $B$ is a $0/1$ matrix then $B\mathbf 1\ge 0$ componentwise with equality iff $B=0$.

Comment: He means that entries of B are 0, 1 or -1. 1 if there is an edge going from i to j, and -1 if there is an edge going from j to i.

Comment: What if there is both?

Comment: ... and $0$ if there's both an edge from $i$ to $j$ and from $j$ to $i$?

Comment: Then there's no distinction between pairs of vertices with no edge and with an undirected edge, which is rather odd for a graph representation.

Comment: So that would make $B=I-I^T$ where $I$ is what I would call the adjacencye matrix of a directed graph? Especially, $B=-B^T$?

Comment: ... and then, assuming $A > 0$ means $A$ is (symmetric) positive definite, $C$ is symmetric.  So the special property of the eigenvalues is that they are real.

Comment: And, of course, $0$ is an eigenvalue, with eigenvector $(0,\ldots,0,1,\ldots,1)^T$.

Comment: Sorry everyone I had a mistake in stating the properties of B

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I would like to know the sign of eigenvalues of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some obvious properties (let $A$ be $n\times n$):

1. As $C$ is real symmetric, all its eigenvalues are real.
2. The characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $\det(\lambda^2I + \lambda A - B^TB).$
3. As $A$ is positive definite and the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $A$ is $BA^{-1}B^T$, the nullitiy of $C$ is equal to the nullity of $B$. The null space of $C$ consists of vectors of the form $(0,v^T)^T$, where $B^Tv=0$.
4. $C$ is indefinite. For any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $(\mathbf{1}^T,v^T)C(\mathbf{1}^T,v^T)^T
   =-\mathbf{1}^TA\mathbf{1}-2(\mathbf{1}^Tv)$. Therefore, one can choose $v$ to make the quantity positive or negative at will.

Comment: can any comments be made from a perron frobenius viewpoint

Comment: @dineshdileep Oops. I thought $A>0$ meant $A$ is positive definite (actually I mistook Robert Israel's comment as the OP's). If it means $A$ is entrywise positive instead, then yes, obviously we can say talk about the Perron eigenpair for a negative matrix.